# swift Error generating thumbnail: The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: swift

```
func videoPreviewUiimage(fileName:String) -> UIImage? {
    let filePath = NSString(string: "~/").expandingTildeInPath.appending("/Documents/").appending(fileName)

    let vidURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:filePath)
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: vidURL as URL)
    let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true

    let timestamp = CMTime(seconds: 2, preferredTimescale: 60)

    do {
        let imageRef = try generator.copyCGImage(at: timestamp, actualTime: nil)
        return UIImage(cgImage: imageRef)
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print("Image generation failed with error \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ugly `NSString` bridging and `expandingTildeInPath`.

There is a designated method in `FileManager` to get `~/Documents`.
The method returns `URL` so the step to create an URL can be omitted.

```
let vidURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, 
                                           in: .userDomainMask, 
                               appropriateFor: nil, 
                                       create: false).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
```

Answer (score -1):

I have done this recently and this is the code I used.

```
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: sourceFilePath, options: nil)
let duration = asset.duration.seconds
let data = try Data(contentsOf: file)

let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
let cgImage = try generator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(0, 1), actualTime: nil)
let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

let docDir = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
let imageURL = docDir.appendingPathComponent("\(NSUUID().uuidString).png")
if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
    do {
        try imageData.write(to: imageURL)
    } catch let error {
        print("[ERROR] - Error creating thumbnails for reaction: \(error)")
    }
}
```

I think that the filePath that you are using is not correct. In the code above I create a new image in the Documents directory and then reference it later.